# Avoid to crawling html portion using html-xsl parsing

Tags: html, xml, xslt, ibm-watson, watson-explorer

I'm using Watson Explorer FC 11.0.2 and i'm trying to avoid some html tag from the Watson crawlers. 
At the time I'm using an xslt parser for extracting meta-data, title, and body from an html page with following Path:

"/html/body/div[@class='page-wrapper']/div[@id='main']/ul[@class='sidebar grid-25']"

The parser that im using is the following:

```html
<xsl:template match="/">
<document>

<xsl:apply-templates match="h2[@class='entry-title']" />

<xsl:for-each select="html/head/meta">

<xsl:if test="@name != '' and @content != 'null'">
<content>
<xsl:attribute name="name">
<xsl:value-of select="@name" />
</xsl:attribute>
<xsl:value-of select="@content" />
</content>
</xsl:if>

</xsl:for-each>

<xsl:apply-templates match="div[@class='entry-content']" />

</document>

<xsl:apply-templates match="ul[@class='sidebar grid-25']" />


</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="h2[@class='entry-title']">
<content name="title">
<xsl:value-of select="." />
</content>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="div[@class='entry-content']">
<content name="snippet" weight="1" output-action="summarize" type="html">
<xsl:value-of select="." />
</content>
</xsl:template>


<xsl:template match="ul[@class='sidebar grid-25']">
<xsl:value-of select="." />
</xsl:template>
```

So, how can i handle this problem?
I really don't know where i have to insert the "xsl apply templates" inside my parser for reach the goal.

Thanks in advance guys !

Comment: can you show some example code and desired output sniped which will help us to answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the way to clean-up HTML tags from body using XSLT is:
using **Tidy** from *org.w3c*

e.g.

```
<xsl:template match="/">
    <document>
        <xsl:apply-templates match="h2[@class='entry-title']" />

        <xsl:for-each select="html/head/meta">
            <xsl:if test="@name != '' and @content != 'null'">
                <content>
                    <xsl:attribute name="name">
                        <xsl:value-of select="@name" />
                    </xsl:attribute>
                    <xsl:value-of select="@content" />
                </content>
            </xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each>

        <xsl:apply-templates match="div[@class='entry-content']" />
    </document>

    <xsl:apply-templates select="ul[@class='sidebar grid-25']" />
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="h2[@class='entry-title']">
    <content name="title">
        <xsl:value-of select="htmlparser:parseHTMLtoDocument(.)" />
    </content>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="div[@class='entry-content']">
    <content name="snippet" weight="1" output-action="summarize" type="html">
        <xsl:value-of select="htmlparser:parseHTMLtoDocument(.)" />
    </content>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="ul[@class='sidebar grid-25']">
    <xsl:value-of select="htmlparser:parseHTMLtoDocument(.)" />
</xsl:template>
```

You can create a class named **com.xyz.commons.xsl.HtmlDocumentParser** like below and call it's method:

```
public class HtmlDocumentParser {
private static Logger log = Logger.getLogger(HtmlDocumentParser.class);
private static Log4jPrintWriter log4j = new Log4jPrintWriter(log, Level.WARN);

public static Document parseHTMLtoDocument(final String input) {
    return parseHTMLtoDocument(input, "UTF-8");
}

public static Document parseHTMLtoDocument(final String input, final String encoding) {

    final String htmlInput = String
            .format("<!DOCTYPE HTML><html>\n<head>\n<title>\n</title>\n</head>\n<body>\n%s</body></html>", input);
    Tidy tidy = new Tidy();
    tidy.setInputEncoding(encoding);
    tidy.setOutputEncoding(encoding);
    tidy.setXHTML(true);
    tidy.setXmlOut(true);
    tidy.setEncloseBlockText(true);
    tidy.setEncloseText(true);
    tidy.setMakeBare(true);
    tidy.setMakeClean(true);
    tidy.setWord2000(true);
    tidy.setDropFontTags(true);
    tidy.setQuiet(true);
    tidy.setErrout(log4j);

    Document doc = tidy.parseDOM(new ByteArrayInputStream(htmlInput.getBytes(Charset.forName(encoding))), null);
    return doc;
}}
```